# Springfox: How to manually add api paths to swagger-ui?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

When configuring a `Docket` we have to specify the base package where to look for api endpoints. Is it possible to add manually an endpoint which is not mapped to any controller?

I have a legacy application which is a simple Zuul server but it has a swagger-ui, the goal is to specifiy endpoints that are proxied by zuul?

```
@Bean
public Docket docket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .globalOperationParameters(getHeaders()).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("package.controllers"))
            .additionalApis(Method.PUT, "/my/manual/endpoint") // This does not exist
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

Thanks